# How to create never expires Acess Token for Facebook app

Tags: facebook

I created facebook app, now access token is for 60 days but i want to extend never expires access token .if you have any information please let me know.

Comment: This is not possible. Read the docs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is in the FB API.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as an access token that 'never expires'. Please read the [Access Token Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending). The best you can do is to get a token which is valid for 60 days and extend it after it has expired.

> Native mobile applications using Facebook's SDKs will get long-lived
>   access tokens, good for about 60 days. These tokens will be refreshed
>   once per day when the person using your app makes a request to
>   Facebook's servers. If no requests are made, the token will expire
>   after about 60 days and the person will have to go through the login
>   flow again to get a new token.
>
> Access tokens on the web often have a lifetime of about two hours, but
>   will automatically be refreshed when required. If you want to use
>   access tokens for longer-lived web apps, especially server side, you
>   need to generate a long-lived token. A long-lived token generally
>   lasts about 60 days.

Comment: I have solved it myself but now the problem is when i use the "never expire token" ,it causes error "(#200) The target user has not authorized this action".but when use initial token(1 hrs, 2 month),it works fine